# passing pointer to function in pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to create a thread by passing a function pointer, however at this line

```
pthread_t start_thread(void *func, thread_data *tdata)
```

It gives me --

```
use-hello.c:23: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'void* (*)(void*)
```

Any inputs please...

```
typedef struct thread_data{
int fd;
int threadId;
}thread_data;


pthread_t start_thread(void *func, thread_data *tdata)
{
   pthread_t thread_id;
   int rc;
      printf("In main: creating thread\n");
      rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, func, tdata);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
        }
    return(thread_id);
}


void thread_function1(thread_data *tdata){ 
.
.
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

/* Our file descriptor */
int fd;
int rc = 0;

printf("%s: entered\n", argv[0]);

/* Open the device */
fd = open("/dev/hello1", O_RDWR);

if ( fd == -1 ) {
    perror("open failed");
    rc = fd;
    exit(-1);
}
printf("%s: open: successful, fd=%d\n", argv[0], fd);

//array of function pointers
void (*function[5])(thread_data*);

function[0] = thread_function0;
function[1] = thread_function1;
function[2] = thread_function2; 
function[3] = thread_function3;
function[4] = thread_function4;


//start threads
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    thread_data *tdata[i] = (thread_data*)malloc(sizeof(thread_data));
    tdata[i]->threadId = i;
    tdata[i]->fd = fd;
    printf("starting thread = %d\n",start_thread(function[i]), tdata[i]));
}

while(1) sleep(1); // infinite loop

printf("closing file descriptor..\n");
close(fd);
printf("file descriptor closed..\n");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: The third argument of `pthread_create` must be a `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`, and you try to pass it a `void*`. A `void*` can be implicitly converted to a pointer to any object type, but not function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your declaration of `start_thread`, it takes a `void*` rather than a function pointer.

Change it to:

```
pthread_t start_thread(void *(*func) (thread_data *), thread_data *tdata);
```

A typedef for that function pointer type would simplify both that prototype and your array declaration.

```
typedef void (*thread_func)(thread_data*);
pthread_t start_thread(thread_func func, thread_data *tdata);
thread_func function[5];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mat, Kylo and Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes func as `void*`

```
pthread_t start_thread(void *func, thread_data *tdata)
```

And then you pass it to pthread_create as 3rd argument which should be `void *(*) (void *)`